# Why does this graph doesn’t not show values of y in negative value of x in y=x^(1/n] wheee n is varied

Tags: graphing-functions

So I plotted the graph of y=x^(1/n) where n was varied and I notice that for some values of n like 4.4 , -0.8 left arm of graph was not there I.e. no values of y for negative x . I didn’t understand this . Please explain .

Comment: In general, negative numbers to non-integer exponents are not automatically defined, for example, what do you do with $-1$ to the $1/2$ power, which would be the square root of $-1$? Yes, a few rational exponents like $1/3$ make sense with negative bases, but a typical graphing program simply ignores negative numbers to real non-integer powers because there is no coherent way to define them as real values (other than rational exponents with odd denominators such as $1/3$)

Comment: What would be the general value of n for which we can’t take negative values of x . Like 4.4 contains both 2 , 11, 5 so ?

Comment: In theory, the exponent would need to be rational with an odd denominator in order to work on a negative base, which means if your exponent is $1/n$ then $n$ would have to be rational with odd numerator -- and you'd have to insist that the rational be written in lowest terms. I doubt that typical graphing programs would check for that, since they probably work with floating point (i.e. decimal) representations rather than exact (rational) numbers -- they would simply not evaluate negative bases to non-integer powers in the context of graphing.